# How to make multiple usernames login in symfony2 and fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to make an app where users sign in with two logins (called username and location) and a password. For example:

```
location: mylocation
username: myusername
password: mypassword
```

There can be more than one user with the same username but they have to be in different locations.

I want to modify FosUserBundle to make this but I have no idea how? Anybody can help me? Or maybe I should write my custom user authentication rather than modifying FOSUserBundle? Any advices?

Comment: Quick dirty solution: add another column (`login_name` for example) that contains the concatenated `location` and `username` (with a `:` between), and use that for login. You'll need some extra js on the login page, and to re-generate that field on `setLocation()` and `setUsername()`

Comment: Using the method above by @Vlad would be done better with a event listener in your form type to concatentate the strings rather than relying on javascript

Comment: @Qoop I have no idea how to make an event listener for fosuserbundle login. :(